# Detect Cell Modified or Update in Web Browser Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

I have an Excel located in SharePoint Online Library.
I tried using Intersect to detect any change or update in Column A, Column B will be updated to the month value of the change or update made in respective Column A.

It works well in Microsoft Excel Desktop App, but if I open the Excel in Web browser, the function not firing.

Comment: The Excel web application cannot be automated with VBA. As far as I know, there is a Java Script API for this. However, I do not know any more details about this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview

Answer (score 0):

Check the function and/or formula/VBA. Things like "color" for cells are not available in the Online Excel, nor will VBA and macros work.